# Taskbar is not working properly in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

My laptop was working fine, but some days ago it was slow, so I had to end some tasks' (2 or 3) background processes in Task Manager. From that day on my taskbar didn't work properly. Problems are here.

- When I type in Windows search it doesn't pop up.
- When I right-click the Start button nothing happens. When I left-click a pop-up window appears, so I use left-click to shut it down.
- When I left-click on apps nothing happens. It doesn't show me recent history or unpin an app from the taskbar. Right-click is working properly with some apps here.
- The taskbar tray doesn't show any notification pop-up window. I can't even change my volume up and down.
- The calculator app and the Play Store aren't working. I have clicked many times, but nothing happens. I'm not sure about that. I have ended some tasks, what are they?

Comment: @LarsTech, @ Nathan Kuchta, @ jmoerdyk,@ jonrsharpe, @ Jan Dvorak

Answer (score 1):

If you have not rebooted the system from scratch since you did that, I would start there and see if those tasks you ended restart.

It sounds like one of them is needed.

You can check the event viewer/boot degradation to find things that may be slowing it down instead of randomly ending tasks that may be needed.

Comment: This probably should have been a comment on the original question. That said, your advice is sound given the limited information available.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer may not have ever properly shutdown. Win 10 computers have hibernation set as default, meaning when you shutdown, it is just actually saving the state. You can try a full shutdown to see if that helps the problem by running the command `shutdown /s /f /t 0` in **CMD** or **PowerShell**. You can also try restarting explorer.exe by finding it in Task Manager under processes (or services depending on your version), and killing it. Then you can go File > Run, and enter `explorer.exe`.